# Submitting a Multiple Step Form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a form using the How TO - Form with Multiple Steps from W3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp) and inserted it into a CRUD system

The form Submits into a MySQL Database that can then be viewed/edited/deleted.

Previously i would use the below code of the button to submit the form and this worked fine. I tried to implement this into the form itself and that does not work. I am unaware of what happens, i have searched through the debugger. But nothing is being sent over to the Database. When i submit it should run a create.php file and that inserts into the DB. This code file doesnt seem to want to insert into the DB. I dont think the form is actually submitting...

```html
<?= $data['action'] ?>
```

When i would use this in a single form sheet. The data would post by using

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"><?= $data['button'] ?></button>
```

Here is my code -

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("surveyForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the form */
  /* Style the input fields */
  input {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  }
  
  /* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
  input.invalid {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
  }
  
  /* Hide all steps by default: */
  .tab {
    display: none;
  }
  
  /* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
  .step {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  
  /* Mark the active step: */
  .step.active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  /* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
  .step.finish {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
  }
```

```html
<form class="row g-3" id="surveyForm" action="<?= $data['action'] ?>" method="post">
  <!-- Form Start -->

  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">
    <!-- Tab 1 Start -->

    <h1>Contact & Site Details</h1>

    <div class="row">
      <!-- Row 1 Start -->

      <div class="col-md-7">
        <label for="site_name" class="form-label">Site Name*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="site_name" name="site_name" value="<?= $data['record']['site_name'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Enter Site Name" oninput="this.className = ''" required><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Row 1 End -->
  </div>
  <!-- Tab 1 End -->

  <div class="tab">
    <!-- Tab 2 Start -->
    <h1>Questions</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Row 2 Start -->

      <div class="col-12">
        <h6 for="current_machine">1. What is your Current Machine?</h6>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="current_machine" name="current_machine" value="<?= $data['record']['current_machine'] ?? '' ?>" oninput="this.className = ''" placeholder="Leave blank if none"><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Row 2 End -->
  </div>
  <!-- Tab 2 End -->

  <div class="tab">
    <!-- Tab 3 Start -->

    <h1>Site Delivery Info</h1>

    <div class="row">
      <!-- Row 3 Start -->

      <div class="col-12">
        <h6 for="q7">9. What floor is the Machine(s) going to be located on?</h6>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="q7" name="q7" value="<?= $data['record']['q7'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Please enter what floor your machine will be located on"> <br><br>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"><?= $data['button'] ?></button>
    </div>
    <!-- Row 3 End -->
  </div>
  <!-- Tab 3 End -->

  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>

</form>
<!--Form End -->
```

Comment: Please try to clarify what the issue is. The example on W3schools works OK. The snippet here does nothing - likely because of a lack of css? But what precisely does `"Is there a way i can use this in the submit part of the function?"` mean / refer to? What actually does happen with your form when you have completed the final stage? What does `"i am having troubles submitting the form into the MySQL database"` mean - can you not save the data? Does the data not arrive? Are there errors?

Comment: I have updated it. Please let me know if this is acceptable...

Comment: what is `$data['action']`  generating as the form action? Use the console to `inspect` the form. That style of echo does need to be enabled in PHP ini file or at runtime perhaps

Comment: $data['action'] is involved in the template data. $data['action'] => 'create.php', so it loads the file. which posts the form to the db

Answer (score 0):

It's listening for Button type "Submit" not Button.

In your Javascript, try this..

```
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // change button type to submit before the form gets submitted:

    var btn=document.getElementById("nextBtn");
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');

    document.getElementById("surveyForm").submit();
    return false;
}
```